# Display a sequence of images in 1 position stored in an object js

Tags: javascript, object, sequence

I'd like to have an object of images and then loop through them to display each one with a certain interval of time between each one.

Store images in an object:

```
var images = [
  { name: 'image1', image: 'image1.jpg' }, 
  { name: 'image2', image: 'image2.jpg' }, 
  { name: 'image3', image: 'image3.jpg' }
]
```

Create a loop to go through each image in the object and each time it cycles through it changes the source of the div to the image.

Lastly i'd like the images to stop cycling through the loop of a button is clicked.

So far I have the above object setup along with a function containing a counter which loops through the items in the object.

```
 var add = (function() {
        var counter = images.length - 1;
        return function() {
            if(counter === images.length - 1) {
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter+=1;
            }
            return counter;
        }
    })();
```

I then used setInterval to change the src every 0.5 seconds.

```
setInterval(
    function() {
     var imageDiv = document.getElementById('image');

     var tester = images[add()];

     imageDiv.src = tester.image;

    }
, 500);
```

The above seems to console log the correct image OK, but its not changing the source and displaying one of the images once every 0.5 seconds.

Can anyone provide a pointer to help me update the src?

Thank you

Comment: Please, make me know if the solution I provided have worked. Also you can ask for further explanation if you didn't understand some part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Loop is not necessary here, you can manually keep track of the Current Image like i did with the `imgIndex` variable and increment it each time the function `changeImg()` is called. I set that variable back to 0 after it reaches the last image, so it will repeat the Image-Order afterwards.

In the setInterval Function (2nd Argument) you can set the Time each Image should be displayed.

> You dont need to worry about Images being loaded multiple times, since
>   we just replace the `src` attribute the Browser will handle it.

Any further questions?

```js
images = [
  {"name":"img1", "src":"https://phinest.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Maya_Beano_Phinest_4-800x800.jpg"},
  {"name":"img2", "src":"https://www.pixel-creation.com/wp-content/uploads/3d-nature-wallpapers-wallpaper-cave-800x800.jpg"},
  {"name":"img3", "src":"https://img00.deviantart.net/5fdc/i/2009/162/9/0/nature_stock_14_by_dezzan_stock.jpg"},
  {"name":"img4", "src":"https://www.secretescapes.com/inlombardia/img/content/link--nature.jpg"},
  {"name":"img5", "src":"https://www.mappingmegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/sunset-2177324_1920-001.jpg"}
];
imgIndex = 0;

function changeImg(){
  document.getElementById("slideshow").src = images[imgIndex].src;
  if(images.length > imgIndex+1){
    imgIndex++;
  } else {
    imgIndex = 0;
  }
}

changeImg();
setInterval(changeImg, 2000)
```

```html
<img id="slideshow" src=""/>
```

Comment: brilliant, i have just added clearInterval to a button to control the image stopping when the user needs to. I will eventually add this to a touch function which will stop the image rotating when the user flicks the screen upwards :-)

Comment: Glad i was able to help, the clearInterval() Function is a nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the counter fn. Please try this; it starts from 0, ends on images.length - 1 and then restarts to 0:

```js
var add = (function(len) {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    if(counter === len) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    return counter++;
  }
})(images.length); // It's not required, but I also recommend you passing images.length as a parameter
```

Also, if you want to stop the interval, you just have to do something like this:

```js
// Now myInterval is a numbered ID
var myInterval = setInterval(myFn, myTime);

// Something happens here and then..

// Your interval is stopped
clearInterval(myInterval);
```